# Play a video with vlcj on a Mac

Tags: vlc, vlcj

Hi I'm trying to get a video running with vlcj on a mac.
I tried several things but everywhere there is something wrong.
The Programm is starting up, but there is no video playing. Does anyone know how to handle vlcj on a mac? 
My intentions are to play a rtsp stream on a mac with java. I tried it first with opencv and now vlcj but didn't succed.

Are there any good examples how to do that on a mac or does anyone know why it is not working?

Thanks

Code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;

public class VideoExample {

    private final EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {


        uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibC.INSTANCE.setenv("VLC_PLUGIN_PATH", "/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/plugins", 1);

        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib");
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new VideoExample(args);
            }
        });
    }

    private VideoExample(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("vlcj Tutorial");

        mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();

        frame.setContentPane(mediaPlayerComponent);

        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("/test.m4v");

    } 
}
```

Bug:

```
[main] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info - vlcj: <version not available>
[main] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info - java: 1.8.0_45 Oracle Corporation
[main] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info - java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
[main] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info - os: Mac OS X 10.10.4 x86_64
[AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlcFactory - vlc: 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax), changeset 2.2.1-0-ga425c42
[AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlcFactory - libvlc: /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libvlc.dylib
JavaVM WARNING: JAWT_GetAWT must be called after loading a JVM
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load JAWT
    at com.sun.jna.Native.getWindowHandle0(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Native$AWT.getComponentID(Native.java:1879)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.getComponentID(Native.java:253)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.CanvasVideoSurface.attach(CanvasVideoSurface.java:76)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.attachVideoSurface(DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.java:162)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.onBeforePlay(DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.java:327)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.DefaultMediaPlayer.play(DefaultMediaPlayer.java:804)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.DefaultMediaPlayer.playMedia(DefaultMediaPlayer.java:265)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.DefaultMediaPlayer.playMedia(DefaultMediaPlayer.java:256)
    at VideoExample.<init>(VideoExample.java:46)
    at VideoExample.<init>(VideoExample.java:34)
    at VideoExample$1.run(VideoExample.java:29)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks

Here is everything explained step by step
http://capricasoftware.co.uk/#/projects/vlcj/tutorial/direct-rendering

the rtsp stream works perfectly fine if you are ok with 3 seconds delay

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can reduce that delay by passing something like "--sout-rtp-caching 200" when you create your media player factory. I don't recall the exact switch.

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly like this: `String [] options =  {" :live-caching=200"};
mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(rtspURL, options);`

Answer (score 2):

This is a well-known and well-documented issue with vlcj (and in fact other applications) on OSX with a JDK later than 1.6.

I know link-only answers are not the best, but there's way too much information on this problem to repeat here, so check https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/issues/205.

Essentially you can't use the embedded media player component since it relies on a heavyweight AWT component (a `Canvas`) to 'host' the video, and in JDK 1.7 and later on OSX there is no heavyweight AWT anymore.

So on OSX either use the so-called "direct" rendering approach with vlcj, or use JDK 1.6.